# how to set multi type for one field (with type of array or object) of schema (Typescript , NestJs)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, schema

I want to set multi type for one field of my schema

like this:

```
@Schema({ validateBeforeSave: true, _id: false })
class example1 {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

@Schema({  validateBeforeSave: true, _id: false })
class example2 {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

@Schema({ collection: 'user', validateBeforeSave: true, timestamps: true })
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: example1 | example2 })
  firstProp: string;

  @Prop({ type: example1[] | example2[] })
  secondProp: example1[] | example2[];
}
```

I want property with two type and an array with two or more type and i want to that mongoDB validate my schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use refpath for multiple object type on [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref)

and for multiple array type you can do like this:

```
@Prop([
    { type: example1 },
    { type: example2 },
  ])
  payMethod?: PayMethod[];
```

it's equal to this

```
@Prop({
  type:[
    { type: example1 },
    { type: example2 },
  ]
})
  payMethod: PayMethod[];
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like Mr. Alireza's answered is pretty decent.